# globalTeardown works locally but fails on Kubernetes workload

Tags: jestjs, rancher-desktop

I'm trying to run a simple jest setup on kubernetes. Until now it works fine on my local workstation (WLS2 on WIN10).

PROBLEM: When I add a `globalTeardown` to my package.json, the function fails in my kubernetes workload, but works when executed locally. Both of the runs are invoked by `npm run test`

The log of the kubernetes workload prints this error:

```sh
[...] // Tests are executed as usual
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       2 failed, 1 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.57s
 reporter is created on: /opt/app/public/report.html
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe',
  path: '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgAvAG8AcAB0AC8AYQBwAHAALwBwAHUAYgBsAGkAYwAvAHIAZQBwAG8AcgB0AC4AaAB0AG0AbAAiAA=='
  ]
}
```

I have no idea how this can be connected to Powershell, as the used image is based in Ubuntu. Could it be an caused by using Rancher Desktop integrated to WSL2?

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "endpoint-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test utility for testing endpoints of backends from a kubernetes cluster",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --forceExit",
    "watch": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "run": "node --experimental-vm-modules index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.3.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^3.5.0",
    "jest-html-reporters": "^3.0.7",
    "jest-standard-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "winston": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./tests/setup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./tests/customTeardown.js",
    "reporters": [
      "jest-standard-reporter",
      [
        "jest-html-reporters",
        {
          "publicPath": "./public",
          "filename": "report.html",
          "openReport": true,
          "inlineSource": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

`./tests/customTeardown.js`

```js
export default async function () {
    console.log("Done");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I found this not to happen, when using Kind instead of Rancher Desktop. So this seems to be an integration issue of Rancher Desktop.